# need regex help to extract hex value

Tags: javascript, regex

With this examples I would like to extract the hash value without the `:`

```
a=foo:val
a=bar:val
a=hash:sha-256 04:78:88:00:46:C0:A5:00:7A:46:64:12:70:EE:53:13:89:FF:41:9A:DE:21:E3:0D:96:36:E0:7F:0A:92:81:69
a=baz:val
```

Expecting to get:

- 0478880046C0A5007A46641270EE531389FF419ADE21E30D9636E07F0A928169

So it has to find a line that starts with `a=hash:sha-256`and extract all hex values after that

Comment: `str.split()` is a great start https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: i want to use regex

Comment: I cannot see your attempt at this in your post?

Comment: There isn't much i can show you because i suck at regex and capture group, look behind etc, and i only need the regex. so there is not even a point in trying cuz the regex everyone provide looks different

Comment: There is no point in trying?! It would at least encourage responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to achieve the result. where [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method can be used to get the string from the line and  [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove `:` from the string.

```
var res = str
        // get the string after sha-256 in capturing group
        .match(/a=hash:sha-256\s+(.*)/)[1]
        // apply replace to remove all :
        .replace(/:/g, '');
```

```js
var str = `a=foo:val
a=bar:val
a=hash:sha-256 04:78:88:00:46:C0:A5:00:7A:46:64:12:70:EE:53:13:89:FF:41:9A:DE:21:E3:0D:96:36:E0:7F:0A:92:81:69
a=baz:val`;

var res = str.match(/a=hash:sha-256\s+(.*)/)[1].replace(/:/g, '');

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
let str = `a=foo:val
a=bar:val
a=hash:sha-256 04:78:88:00:46:C0:A5:00:7A:46:64:12:70:EE:53:13:89:FF:41:9A:DE:21:E3:0D:96:36:E0:7F:0A:92:81:69
a=baz:val`;

let output = str.split('\n')
             .find(a => a.startsWith('a=hash:sha-256'))
             .replace(/a=hash:sha-256|:/g, '');

console.log(output)
```